# C# Webbrowser Tab Key

Tags: c#, vsto

So I'm working on VSTO in C# that will display a side task pane that will navigate out to website via a User Control with a docked Webbrowser. I have everything there working fine but what is not working is when you are in the Webbrowser and you press the Tab Key it does not shift the focus from the username down to the password text box. The website is wrote in PHP don't know if that would make a difference. You are able to tab on the website down to the password text box. And I'm trying to figure out how to allow for this tab function to work. Any help would be great!

Comment: can you ultimately set the focus to the name of the control if Tabing or TabStop doesn't work..??? so if your control name is txtMycontrol you could just write txtMyControl.Focus(); on the on exit of the field next to that control..? does this make sense..

Comment: But the text boxes are in a website, so I can't access them like I could if the text boxes were right on the WPF it self.

Comment: can you perhaps redefine the issue that you are having.. I may be not be understanding what the issue is here..thanks

Comment: Alright So I have a WPF that is a taskpane on the side of Powerpoint, that has a Webbrowser docked to it. Inside of the webbrowser they will access the login page out on our website. Once they click inside of the browser and type in their user name, most people hit the tab key to access the password box on the web page. Whenever I hit the tab key inside the Webbrowser nothing happens at all. I'm trying to recreate this. I know its not the website because I can stick a webbrowers on a windows form and the tab work perfectly fine. Seems to be an issue with the WPF.

Comment: sounds like there are some key assignments for example if the tab key is hit they are triggering or assigning the #13 or Enter Key..

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue in a custom task pane in Excel, which I've developed in C++. I've got a simple test HTML page and I find that tab key presses are being filtered out somehow.

Comment: Also the Delete key doesn't work (but Backspace does).

Comment: And this was the fix in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775447/tab-key-support-in-an-iwebbrowser2-control - no idea if that could be implemented in a VSTO, so can't put it as the answer here.