# How to pass WM_KEYDOWN message to IWebBrowser2 instance?

Tags: c++, windows, iwebbrowser2

I'm loading an embedded browser within a parent application using the `IWebBrowser2` interface. My code is compiled as a dll, i.e. the browser component is dynamically loaded at runtime via a plugin interface.

The problem I'm having is that applications that load my dll are trapping certain keydown messages, and they are therefore not reaching my `IWebBrowser2` instance.

I am therefore capturing these messages using the `SetWindowsHookEx()` API in my dll.

How can I then forward the `WM_KEYDOWN` or `WM_CHAR` messages to my `IWebBrowser2` instance such that they could e.g. be used to enter text in a focused text box within the browser?

Comment: Does the browser control have keyboard focus when events are lost?

Comment: @Anders I think so. The fact that some events get through and others are blocked would suggest focus is gained, right?

Comment: Setting a hook is a pretty big hammer.  I think you'd be better off trying to understand why the host application isn't passing those messages to your window.  You also said that some are coming, but others aren't.  Have you detected any patterns?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Yeah, the hosts aren't passing messages because they're stealing them for their own keyboard shortcuts (this is an audio plugin, the hosts are [DAW software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_workstation)). Some hosts don't steal any keys at all, some steal only a few (e.g. spacebar for play), some steal almost all.

Comment: Are the hosts actually stealing the keypresses (e.g., directly in the message loop) or are they receiving them because their window has the focus?  Hooking to steal them back seems destined to make things worse for the user, either by breaking the host's keyboard shortcuts or by making some keypresses do multiple things simultaneously.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy My component definitely has focus. I've now got this working. My plan is to only "steal back" the keypresses when my component has focus. It seems reasonable that users would expect a component to receive keypresses when it has focus :)

Comment: Is your window on the same thread as the host application's window?  If not, they might both believe that they have focus.  I think you need to ensure both windows are on the same thread input queue so that focus behaves rationally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem sits in host application's message queue implementation, where some messages are handled instead of delivering, for example to implement hotkeys. Since you can't change their code, hooking the message queue sounds like a reasonable approach.

The following code snippet demonstrates both problem and solution:

```
#define WINDOW_CLASS _T("StackOverflow_41911104")

HINSTANCE   g_Instance = 0;
HHOOK       g_Hook = 0;
HWND        g_TargetWindow = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

HWND CreateMainWindow()
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = g_Instance;
    wcex.hIcon          = nullptr;
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = nullptr;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = WINDOW_CLASS;
    wcex.hIconSm        = nullptr;

    ATOM windowClass    = RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
    HWND mainWindow     = CreateWindowW(WINDOW_CLASS, WINDOW_CLASS, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 400, 400, nullptr, nullptr, g_Instance, nullptr);

    g_TargetWindow      = CreateWindow(_T("Edit"), nullptr, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE, 0, 0, 300, 300, mainWindow, (HMENU)1000, g_Instance, nullptr);

    return mainWindow;
}

HACCEL CreateAccelerators()
{
    ACCEL acceleratorsList[] =
    {
        {FVIRTKEY, 'R', 1000},
        {FVIRTKEY, 'T', 1001},
    };

    return CreateAcceleratorTable(acceleratorsList, _countof(acceleratorsList));
}

void ProcessHookMessage(MSG* a_Message)
{
    // Only affect our window and its children
    if ((g_TargetWindow != a_Message->hwnd) && !IsChild(g_TargetWindow, a_Message->hwnd))
        return;

    // Deliver the message directly
    TranslateMessage(a_Message);
    DispatchMessage(a_Message);

    // Do not allow to process this message the second time
    a_Message->message = WM_NULL;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK Hook_GetMsgProc(int a_Code, WPARAM a_WParam, LPARAM a_LParam)
{
    if ((HC_ACTION == a_Code) && (PM_REMOVE == a_WParam))
        ProcessHookMessage((MSG*)a_LParam);

    return CallNextHookEx(g_Hook, a_Code, a_WParam, a_LParam);
}

void InstallHook()
{
    g_Hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, Hook_GetMsgProc, g_Instance, GetCurrentThreadId());
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int)
{
    g_Instance = hInstance;

    HWND mainWindow = CreateMainWindow();
    HACCEL hAccelTable = CreateAccelerators();
    InstallHook();

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        // The problem lurks here: some messages are handled directly and never reach the target window
        if (TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
            continue;

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this code snippet, if you comment out `InstallHook()` call, you won't be able to print <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>T</kbd>, because these keys are used for accelerator table. However, with `InstallHook()`, the hook forces normal message queue behavior and everything works as normal.

The suggested hook code have the following points of interest:

1. It only affects your window and nothing else
2. It works the same way as the usual message queue would, instead of messing with `SendMessage` / `PostMessage`
3. It prevents double-effect of messages that were not intercepted by hosting application

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted this answer because it's very close to what I now have working, except that I'm also using `PostMessage()`. I'll look into eliminating this though, based on your `ProcessHookMessage()`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the root problem is that your window is on a different thread than the host application's window, which can confuse the focus state.  You can easily get into situations where the host window and the hosted window both believe they have the focus.

The solution to that is to create your window on the same thread as the parent window, and, if that's not possible (e.g., because of the plugin model or because the plugin is run in a separate process), use [AttachThreadInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956(v=vs.85).aspx).

I haven't used a web browser control in many years, but I recall one project long ago, where we had similar issues when we added the web browser control as a child of a window in another process.  Using AttachThreadInput there solved a lot of bugs.  The drawback was that a bug in either thread (like a hang) effectively hangs both threads.  We also had to be careful to detach the threads during teardown.

Comment: This sounds plausible. Problem is, according to Spy++ my UI *is* on the same thread as the host application's window. I've actually manage to get keyboard input working now by using a combination of `SetWindowsHookEx()` and `PostMessage()`. Not getting mouse wheel events though. Argh!

Answer (score 0):

It seems, this is a bit trickier than the usual sending a message:

Firstly, you will need to obtain the In place active object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691299(v=vs.85).aspx) of your web browser and then call the `TranslateAccelerator` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693360(v=vs.85).aspx) on it.

Some very high level pseudocode would look like:

```
HRESULT hr;
IOleInPlaceActiveObject* pIOIPAO;

hr = webBrowser2->QueryInterface(webBrowser2,
           &IID_IOleInPlaceActiveObject, (LPVOID*)&pIOIPAO);

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
     result = pIOIPAO->lpVtbl->TranslateAccelerator(pIOIPAO, msg);
}
```

where `msg` is the message (`MSG`) you should populate accordingly, and `webBrowser2` is your `IWebBrowser2`.

PS: Didn't try this code, use at your own risk :)

Comment: Thanks. IWebBrowser2 doesn't seem to have a member `lpVtbl`. Looking around on the web it seems that these are part of a C interface, do you know what the C++ equivalent is?

Comment: Looking a bit more at `TranslateAccelerator()` I think you may have misunderstood the question. I'm not looking to send accelerator keys as such to my `IWebBrowser2` component, but just regular keypresses. I can capture the keydown and print the chars to a debug console, I just can't figure out how to pass these on to the web component.

Comment: `QueryInterface` is part of `IUnknown` if I understood correctly. Fixed answer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682521(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Didn't do this low level Windows hacking for a while, but if I remember correctly `TranslateAccelerator` received the `msg` which contained the key . Please try and let me know if it works or not, don't have access anymore to the old codebase this code was in... :(

Comment: OK, adapting the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16787675/172218) I'm able to call `TranslateAccelerator()` as you describe. The call succeeds (non-zero return), but essentially does nothing. I don't get a `WM_CHAR` or `WM_KEYDOWN` in my `IWedBrowser2` instance. It feels like I should be calling [PostMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx) but it's not clear to me how I should obtain the relevant `HWND`